# Can apache or nginx act as load balancer for two different applications one with session stickiness and one without

Tags: apache, nginx

Can apache or nginx act as load balancer for two different applications one with session stickiness and one without.

i.e.

- App1 is deployed on Node1, Node2 and Node3
- App2 is deployed on Node4, Node5 and Node6

App1 needs session stickiness where as App2 is a set of stateless APIs hence does not need session stickiness.

This [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) from apache documentation does show that stickiness is an attribute of application cluster and if two clusters are defined with appropriate boundaries it should be feasible and sufficient to define the above configuration in a single Apache instance

Question is would this be a good design? and if there are any further concerns with such a deployment?

Comment: The short answer is yes, you can do that.